# Trouble on running the command 'git remote' in order to deploy a Ruby on Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, git, deployment

I am trying to deploy my Ruby on Rails 3.0.9 application so I set the following:

```
git remote add origin ssh://user@host/~/git/application_name.git
```

When I run the command

```
git push origin master
```

I get this error (notice: the "Unkn" string is "cut" on outputting):

```
fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: Unkn
```

So, after read [this git faq](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#protocol_error%3a_bad_line_length_character), I run the following commands:

```
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin ssh user@host/~/git/application_name.git
```

Now, when I run the command

```
 git push origin master
```

I get this error:

```
fatal: 'ssh' does not appear to be a git repository
```

---

As wrote in the git faq documentation I try also to run the command

```
ssh user@host echo testing commands
```

but I get the following

```
Unknown command 'echo testing commands'
```

---

**What is the problem? How can I solve that?**

---

I also tryed the following:

```
 1. git remote add origin user@host:~/git/application_name.git
 2. git remote add origin user@host/~/git/application_name.git
```

for which I get respectively the following errors:

```
 # The terminal asks me to insert the server password
 1. fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: Unkn

 # The terminal does not asks me to insert the server password
 2. fatal: 'user@host:~/git/application_name.git' does not appear to be a git repository
```

---

**UPDATE**

**~/.bashrc**

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return

# don't put duplicate lines in the history. See bash(1) for more options
# ... or force ignoredups and ignorespace
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:ignorespace

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "$debian_chroot" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
        # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
        # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
        # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
        color_prompt=yes
    else
        color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\0
33[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dirco
lors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
#if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
#    . /etc/bash_completion
#fi
```

**~/.profile**

```
# ~/.profile: executed by Bourne-compatible login shells.

if [ "$BASH" ]; then
  if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
  fi
fi

mesg n
```

**~/.bash_profile**

```
# empty!!!
```

Comment: It says to just run this command `ssh user@git.example.com echo testing commands` to test to see if it's working. In the command you're typing `user@host/~/git/application_name.git` is not being seen, and git thinks that you're trying to add a remote named `origin` at the address `ssh`.

Comment: take a look at your `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile` and `.profile` files on the server and try taking out any echo statements. Read [here](http://www.bramschoenmakers.nl/node/303) for more info

Comment: @redEvo I had another Terminal open. So I did logout and closed that but the problem persists.

Comment: [This site](https://wincent.com/wiki/fatal:_protocol_error:_bad_line_length_character) suggests problems with differences in versions (maybe your version of git is newer than the server's and is causing conflicts), but there are also links at the bottom of the page talking about the same error (including the git faq you mentioned before).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the `git remote` syntax wrong. For SSH-accessible remote repositories, the repository should be in format `user@host:path/repo.git`, i.e. in your case:

```
git remote add origin user@host:~/git/application_name.git
```

Comment: Hm, interesting. Try doing just the `ssh user@host`. What does it print?

Comment: The terminal asks me the password, I write that and then I have access to the server: all works running 'ssh user@host'.

Comment: What's the remote OS? What shell is set up on that machine? You can determine the latter by doing `grep user /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f7`

Comment: The OS is Ubuntu 10.04 LTS. The shell is '/bin/bash'.

Comment: Can you post (if they exist) your `~/.bashrc`, `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, `/etc/profile`, `/etc/profile.d/*` and `/etc/bash.bashrc` somewhere (of course, strip anything valuable before)? Looks like one of these files screws up everything with some unexpected output.

Comment: It is a little bit long... are you sure I have to report all?

Comment: The offending command may be anywhere. You can omit the ones in `/etc` for a first try, through; it's unlikely that they were actually changed.

Comment: I outputted the first three as you asked.

Comment: Also, given that the `echo` command is failing, there may be something with the path or aliases. Try doing `env | grep PATH` and `type echo`; the latter should print `echo is a shell builtin`.

Comment: I've set up an account with your .profile and .bashrc on my server, and `git push` works just fine.

Comment: 'env | grep PATH' => 'PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games' and 'type echo' => 'echo is a shell builtin'.

Comment: I think you should consider attaching the files in `/etc`. There is nothing wrong with the files you've posted.

Comment: At this time the directory (the absolute path) where is located my git file and the file name are something like the following '/srv/www/mysite.com/git/mysite.com.git'. Is it right?

Comment: Your problem is much more fundamental than a misspelled path (in that case, git would just say that `fatal: 'whatever' does not appear like a git repository`. There is something that prevents you from using non-interactive shell sessions on the server. (Honestly, I have no idea what may be that. I've never experienced anything even nearly similar.)

Comment: So, I should ask to the server provider (it is Linode)... (?)

Comment: There is no harm trying. I'd suggest showing them the output of `ssh user@host echo something`, as that is *highly* suspicious, and also is an easy, repeatable test which shows what's wrong with the server.

Comment: OK, I will advice them and I will report here for you the problem description.

Comment: Nothing to do. They said me to install PuTTY and ask to Putty developers to solve related issues.

Comment: That's just nonsense. Why should developers of some SSH client you don't even use solve the problems caused by *server misconfiguration by the hoster*? Maybe you should consider switching to another hoster... or, maybe, just telling them you're about to will be motivating enough.